# Page extends beyond the viewport on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport

I spent 2 days on figuring out why this [page](https://camerabebelusului.ro/) - is extending beyond the viewport when viewing on mobile devices.

It seems that there is at least one element with a width of 830px - but I was not able to find which one.

[image]

If someone finds where is the problem, I am also interested in knowing how to investigate such problems. Because I check the inspector and I could not find anything relevant - it might be a 1px element height somewhere...

Comment: can you please share link from which we inspect the code ?

Comment: You could give the page tag a overflow:hidden

Comment: @UnmeshD - link was already provided. Here it is again - https://camerabebelusului.ro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT --

I've found the issue, you have a `width: 800px;` on this class: `#socialnetworks .socialnetworks_menu`.

To find issues like this, just try deleting elements in dev tools untill you find the problem area and then work through to narrow it down.

OLD solution:
Adding `overflow: hidden` to `.footer_bottom` has fixed the issue for me, although I couldn't see what it was that was pushing the content out so wide.

Comment: Thank you Sam - you saved me from a big headache!